# How to shake login form on error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a login page with HTML and CSS. It's fully functional and all that stuff. However, when login fails I want the login form to shake. How do I make it shake. Right now, it does nothing.

Here is my HTML/CSS/JavaScript. If more code is needed, please tell me.

HTML

```
<div class="input">
    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="error">${error}</div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
        <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
    </c:if>
    <div class="email">
        <input type="text" name="username"
            placeholder="Example@email.com"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="password">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="*********"></input>
    </div>
</div>

<input class="login_btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="">
```

CSS

```
.container .login_component .login_wrap .login_wp .input input {
    width: 290px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
}

.container .login_component .login_wrap .login_wp .input .email {
    height: 53px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background:
        url("http://xiilab.mynetgear.com:81/c.hwang/rems/images/login/input.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.container .login_component .login_wrap .login_wp .input .password {
    height: 53px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background:
        url("http://xiilab.mynetgear.com:81/c.hwang/rems/images/login/input.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.container .login_component .login_wrap .login_wp .login_btn {
    height: 55px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background:
        url("http://xiilab.mynetgear.com:81/c.hwang/rems/images/login/login_btn.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    border: none;
    width: 310px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.input').addClass('ahashakeheartache');
});

$('.input').on('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e){
      $('.input').delay(200).removeClass('ahashakeheartache');
});
```

Comment: It might be easier for people to answer without having to dig in to a big piece of code first. If the *real* code isn't really needed, it could be better to give a very simple example or even leave the code fully. :)

Answer (score 11):

If you use [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) you can create that effect. Here is the [github](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) project where you can download the source code. There are other effects you can check out too.

Code for shaking from animate.css:

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.animated.hinge {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.animated.bounceIn,
.animated.bounceOut {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
  animation-duration: .75s;
}

.animated.flipOutX,
.animated.flipOutY {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
  animation-duration: .75s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  from, to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  from, to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.shake {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake;
  animation-name: shake;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.submit').click(function(e){
       // Code to check login
       // If fail
        $('.input').addClass('animated shake');
     });
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Java Dev so I don't know a whole lot about HTML. Could you help me use this code and implement it into mine?

Comment: @bmarkham In your css you have to add animate.css and then just add the class animated and shake.  When you check if the password is correct or wrong you can add the class shake or other classes from animated.css. See edited answer

Comment: Copy the code for shaking from animate.css above, and add the class "shake" to the div that contains your login when login fails

Comment: Ugh I hate to be that "just gimme code" guy here, but I've tried to write code to check for login fail and it still does nothing. I'm not sure if it's the JS, the HTML or the CSS. Although I'm fairly certain that it's the JS.

Answer (score 9):

Use simple animation in Jquery
include the jquery UI

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    $(document).on('click', '#yoursubmitdiv', function(){

    //code if login fails

      $( "#yourloginfield" ).effect( "shake" ); // this will shake your div



    });
```

Comment: Don't post jQuery answers to non-jQuery questions.

Comment: @JosiahKeller Nonsense. Look at the given JavaScript sample. Clearly JQuery. It's not that this answer is misplaced; the question is improperly tagged.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist You're right. I'll amend my criticism to "Don't post jQuery UI answers to vanilla jQuery questions."

Comment: @JosiahKeller Haha now that I can get behind. (Also I'm sure you have to say this 20 times a day. I just didn't want people to read your comment and get the wrong idea then downvote because of it.)

Comment: Sorry I'll tag JQuery. I'm really clueless to webpage stuff and I've done a lot of research to try to do this.

Comment: ooh i'm sorry. OP never mentioned he didn't want to use jquery. I just answer to the question

Answer (score 3):

I would actually recommend to use plain Javascript here, keep it simple but at the same not too simple. Not just `shake`, and not 50 lines of code. Please ask if something is unclear with the code, tried to keep it as compact as possible.

```js
var box1Left1 = 100, box1Left2, keepShaking = true;
var originalLeftPos = parseInt(document.getElementById("box1").style.left);
 
setTimeout(stopShake, 1000); //Shake for how long
function stopShake() { keepShaking = false; }
  
setInterval(shake, 10); //Set shorter interval for faster shake
function shake() {
  if ( keepShaking == true ) {
    if ( box1Left1 < originalLeftPos + 5 ) { // "+5" = The shake distance. Go right. 
      box1Left1++; 
      document.getElementById("box1").style.left = box1Left1 + "px"; 
      box1Left2 = box1Left1;
    }
    if ( box1Left1 >= (originalLeftPos + 5) ) { // Go left. 
      box1Left2--; 
      document.getElementById("box1").style.left = box1Left2 + "px"; 
    }
    if( box1Left2 == originalLeftPos ) { box1Left1 = box1Left2; } // Go Right Again 
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" style="position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 50px; background-color: #aa39fc;">
  Incorrect Password
</div>
```

Comment: I am unsure if this code shakes when I click the login button.

Comment: @bmarkham It wont, this is just an example. If you were looking for something to copy and paste I think you have a slightly distorted approach on the help you get here.

Comment: No, I'm just looking for help that can apply to all of my problems, not just one.

Comment: @bmarkham Soo, was the shaking-problem not the only problem to be solved here? :)

Comment: You should assign setInterval to a constant then stopShake should equal { endInterval(myInterval) }. I wonder how much code out there is aimlessly firing an interval :P

Answer (score 0):

## Shake a React Component

Theres some pretty wild code going on this question - keep it simple.

**Notes**:

• If you have a plain old html/JS page, you could adjust the `const form` in the code below to equal `document.getElementById('logInCard')`. To use `refs` (React.js), I have given my element the prop `ref='logInCard'`.

• The use of `async` `await` to make sure that the element has been found before trying to use it.

• I moved the `leftMargin`, you could change that to whatever you'd like to adjust.

• The ternary operator flips the sign of variable `px` then moves its value closer to 0 by `1px`, giving it an ease-out effect.

• The element you are trying to move should have a `position` property of `relative` or `absolute`.

• `px` converges to zero, so we `clearInterval()` at `1px` which means margin will be back at `0px`.

• Increase `px` to get a wider shake. 50 in `setInterval()` is milliseconds between movements.

• Don't forget to clear the interval at some point so it doesn't keep running!

```
shakeYourTailFeather = async () => {
    const form = await this.refs.logInCard.style;
    const interval = setInterval(move, 50);
    let px = 6;
    function move() {
        form.marginLeft = px + 'px';
        px = px < 0 ? ((px * -1) - 1) : ((px * -1) + 1);
        if (px === 1) clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!login.success) { // Your login failure criteria here
        this.shakeYourTailFeather();
    }
}
```